# Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I wan't to kill a process by it's path. But when I use this code I get a win32Exception.

> Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed

My changed the target build to x64 but I still get the same error.

```
 Process[] Processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("iw4");
 if (Processes.Length >= 1)
 {
    for (int i = 1; i < Processes.Length; i++)
    {
        Process Process = Processes[i];
        string processPath = Process.MainModule.FileName;

        if (processPath == s + "\\iw4.exe")
        {

            if (!File.Exists(s + "\\localization.txt"))
            {
                Log.Data("killed process!");
                Process.Kill();
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Stack trace:

```
   at System.Diagnostics.NtProcexssManager.GetModuleInfos(Int32 processId, Boolean firstModuleOnly)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.get_MainModule()
   at LocalizationFix.Fix.checkLocalizationFile()
   at LocalizationFix.Init.Main(String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: "Change the target build" is not meaningful.  Change the "Platform target" setting to AnyCPU instead.

Comment: The solution is simple: Retry.  I see the same issue with various languages and "process util" libraries.  All of them eventually fail (randomly) with the same Windows error message.  Retry a few times will solve the issue.  Win32: What a pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in the posted code.  Its most likely in `LocalizationFix.Fix.checkLocalizationFile()`.

The posted has an unrelated problem in that you are skipping the first entry in the process list.  C# uses zero-relative indexing.

Maybe you want something like:

```
foreach (var Process in Process.GetProcessesByName("iw4");
{
   ...
}
```

Also, by convention local variable names are lower Pascal cased.  So use:

```
foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("iw4");
{
   ...
}
```